# Does xmls nodes sequence matter?

Tags: xml

are

```
<parent>
    <first_child>1111111</first_child>
    <second_child>2222222</second_child>
</parent>
```

and

```
<parent>
    <second_child>2222222</second_child>
    <first_child>1111111</first_child>
</parent>
```

should be considered as xmls with the same structure or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically depends on how you define your schema, e.g. with XSD you can use `all` if order does not matter or `sequence` if it does. See the [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp) for details.

Answer (score 2):

It entirely depends on what's going to interpret the XML.

Imagine it's actually HTML, and these are paragraph tags... obviously the order matters. In other cases, it may not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the schema that is used to validate it.